# How to calculate the average value of the properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, object

How can I calculate the average value of the properties of an object?

I have this object:

```js
let components = {
  co: [235, 465, 78],
  no: [409, 589, 98],
  nh3: [54, 76, 39]
};
```

I need to separately calculate the average for `co`, `no`, and `nh3`.

Comment: That is not a valid object notation. Curly quotes? Loose numbers? Missing colon? Equal sign? Please, first test that this notation parses.

Comment: Please update the question to include your "attempts".

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries and build a new object with averages.

```js
const
    getAverage = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length,
    components = { co: [235, 465, 78], no: [409, 589, 98], nh3: [54, 76, 39] },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(components)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, getAverage(v)])
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just started learning programming and did not notice any errors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a proper object
2. you can use reduce/length

I use a trick to shorten the decimals, toFixed with a unary plus to convert back to number

There are more tricks here. The object.assign converts the array of object to one object using the `...` spread operator

```js
const components = {
  "co": [235, 465, 78],
  "no": [409, 589, 98],
  "nh3": [54, 76, 39]
}

const avgs = Object
  .assign({}, 
    ...Object.entries(components)
      .map(([key,values]) => 
        ({[key]: +(values
          .reduce((a,b)=>a+b)/values.length)
          .toFixed(2)})
      )
  );
console.log(avgs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I just started learning programming and did not notice any errors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your invalid `object` and tried to get the average values in an array:

```js
let components = {
  co: [235, 465, 78],
  no: [409, 589, 98],
  nh3: [54, 76, 39]
};

let result = [];
Object.keys(components).forEach(function (key) {
  avg = components[key].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / components[key].length;
  result.push(avg);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just started learning programming and did not notice any errors in my code.